# Assigning time intervals for event records - in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I'm fairly new to Python and Data science. I have a dataset which I imported into a dataframe format where each row is an event or activity, recorded as a part of a log of an information system.

- Events are represented by a single record, thus having a single timestamp (instantaneous).
- Activities are represented by more than one record (and timestamp) and also have a 'state' attribute (scheduled,started,suspended,resumed,completed,cancelled) - activity duration is measured from start to completion/cancellation when it was actually worked on, ignoring the scheduled and idle times)

here is a simplified example:

| row # | name | state | type | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | order_created | complete | event | 01/01/2021 17:34:00 |
| 2 | process_order | scheduled | activity | 01/01/2021 17:34:01 |
| 3 | process_order | started | activity | 01/01/2021 18:35:00 |
| 4 | process_order | suspended | activity | 01/01/2021 18:45:00 |
| 5 | process_order | resumed | activity | 02/01/2021 08:30:00 |
| 6 | process_order | completed | activity | 02/01/2021 09:05:00 |
| 7 | order_processed | completed | event | 02/01/2021 09:05:01 |

In this example the total execution time of the 'process_order' activity is the sum of the following time intervals:
lines 3-4 (started..suspended) +
lines 5-6 (resumed..completed) = 10 + 35 = 45 (minutes):

*The events timstamps are not really required here but are part of the dataset.

What is the most efficient way to calculate these execution time intervals (durations) for each activity (the dataframe includes more than 2 million rows)?

thanks

Comment: Are the activity steps always those? Always in this order? Is it guaranteed that a resume won't happen before a suspend? In your 2M rows dataset, are there identifiers to group the orders?

Comment: This is the typical sequence of the activity steps , there are some discrepancies though as this is a real-life dataset. Activity can resume after suspend (this was shown in my example). And yes there are order identifiers but not all acitivities necessarily relate to orders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few assumptions:

- The data is sorted by time
- We are only concerned about 4 states: ['started', 'suspended', 'resumed', 'completed']
- after every start/resume there will  be a stop action.

Here I'm using the time values as ints to simplify things, but it won't change the outcome. We have a sample dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'state': ['scheduled', 'started','suspended','resumed', 'completed'],
                   'time': [1, 10, 25, 35, 45]
                   })
```

We need to create a column where the actions that represent start/resume are indicated by for e.g 1 and the actions that represent suspend/complete are indicated by 0. Other actions don't matter and they can be represented by -1. e.g:

```
def convert(x):
  if x =='started' or x == 'resumed':
    return 1
  elif x== 'suspended' or x == 'completed':
    return 0
  return -1
df['new_state'] = df['state'].apply(lambda x: convert(x))
```

Gives:

```
state   time    new_state
0   scheduled   1   -1
1   started     10  1
2   suspended   25  0
3   resumed     35  1
4   completed   45  0
```

We need to subtract the times with 0 from the times with 1:

```
result = (df[df['new_state'] == 0]['time'] - df[df['new_state'] == 1]['time'].values).sum()
```

This will give the expected results.